# I have Few Confusions Regarding the Trees in Data structure

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

The question is what I have read in the previous slides of the lecture . I have been mentioned that the Height of **tree = Maximum Level + 1** . 
While in a next slide I found that **Maximum Depth = height of a tree** . 
Now can anybody proves that because i have got a tree that isn't satisfying both the statements

[image]

If you see in the above Picture the Maximum Level is exactly the same as the depth and height . Then how is it satisfying the statement . 
***Height Of a tree = Maximum Level + 1***

[image: How the two columns satisfying the relation]

I just add Another image to clarify what i am asking about this is another slide i am having for finding the maximum height .

[image].png

Answer (score 0):

I have learned a formula that is 
level=depth+1
making more clear i would say that
Height of a node x is number of edges in longest path from x to a leaf node.
while the Depth of x is the number of edges in path from root to x. 
I would say we can compare depth and the level as given in formula above but not level and height.

Comment: Ok i got your point but if u see the Second Image **THE HEIGHT OF BINARY TREE* *

8 = 2^3   4(DEPTH / LEVEL) How will you prove this